# Web crawling with appending data to the list

Tags: python

I am very new in Python. I started using Python to crawl my web data, how to achieve the following expected result?

Expected Result

MIMI WORLD貪吃企鵝小冰箱

['N/A']

MIMI 提包指甲機

['$766', '$959', '$912', '$959', '$959', '$990']

Mimi World 甜蜜松鼠屋

['N/A']

迷你mimi提包寵物店

['$695', '$710', '$719', '$684']

Actual Result:
[image: click here]

MIMI WORLD貪吃企鵝小冰箱

['N/A']

MIMI 提包指甲機

['N/A', '$766', '$959', '$912', '$959', '$959', '$990']

Mimi World 甜蜜松鼠屋

['N/A', '$766', '$959', '$912', '$959', '$959', '$990', 'N/A']

迷你mimi提包寵物店

['N/A', '$766', '$959', '$912', '$959', '$959', '$990', 'N/A', '$695', '$710', '$719', '$684']

```
   for i in productprice_div: 
            
            lowest=i.find("span",{"class":"ListItem_priceContent_5WbI9"}).text.strip()
            data.append(lowest)
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually,
this was the origial code:

```
import time
import random
from random import randint
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #A python library to help you to exract HTML information
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
df_keywords = pd.read_excel('mimiworld_keyword.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols="A")
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('mimiworld_keyword.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
index=df_keywords.index
number_of_row=len(index)
ua=UserAgent()



proxies = {
  'http': 'http://192.186.190.73:8080',
  'https': 'http://192.186.190.73:8080'
}

results=[]
data=[]
lowest1=[]

#data_name=[]
#competitor=[]

for i in range (1,number_of_row+1):
    time.sleep(random.randint(2,6))
    keyword_input=worksheet.cell(i,0).value
    print (keyword_input)
    headers={'user-agent': ua.random}
 
    prefix="https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/search/product?disp=list&p="
    sortbyprice="&sort=p"
    url=prefix+keyword_input+sortbyprice
    r=requests.get(url)
    r=requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    #competitor_name_div=soup.findAll("div", {"class":"ListItem_shop_Z_sCW"})
    number_result_div=soup.findAll("div", {"class":"SortBar_sortBar_2CVWp SortBar_store_1U4Du"})
    #producttext_div=soup.findAll("div", {"class":"ListItem_mShop_33fil"})
    productprice_div=soup.findAll("div", {"class":"ListItem_price_2CMKZ"})
    
    if len(productprice_div)==0:
        
        #data_name.append("N/A")
        data.append("N/A")
        #competitor.append("N/A")
        results.append("0")
    
    
    
    #if len(producttext_div)==0:
        #data_name.append("N/A")
        #data.append("N/A")
        #competitor.append("N/A")
        #results.append("0")
    
    for i in number_result_div:
        result=soup.find("span", {"class":"SortBar_sortCount_1LpL9 textEllipsis"}).text.strip()[:-4]
        results.append(result)
        break
    
    
    #for i in producttext_div:
        
        #yeah=soup.find("a", {"class":"ListItem_title_3CH7e textEllipsisLine2"}).text.strip()
        #data_name.append(yeah)
        #break
    
    
    for i in productprice_div: 
        lowest=i.find("span",{"class":"ListItem_priceContent_5WbI9"}).text.strip()
        data.append(lowest)
         
        
        #break
        
        
    #for i in competitor_name_div: 
        
        #competitor_name=i.find("a",{"class":"ListItem_shopName_2wlm8 ListItem_shopLink_1KVF- ListItem_linkHover_1H611 textEllipsisLine2"}).text.strip()
        #competitor.append(competitor_name)
        #break

#print(results)
#print(data_name)
```

I have re-written this to the following:
And now  it works as expected by the poster of this question.

```
import time
import random
from random import randint
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #A python library to help you to exract HTML information
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
df_keywords = pd.read_excel('mimiworld_keyword.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols="A")
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('mimiworld_keyword.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
index=df_keywords.index
number_of_row=len(index)
 

headers = {
    'sec-ch-ua': "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"97\", \"Chromium\";v=\"97\"",
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': "?0",
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': "\"Linux\"",
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': "1",
    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36",
    'accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    'cp-extension-installed': "Yes"
    }

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://192.186.190.73:8080',
  'https': 'http://192.186.190.73:8080'
}

results=[]
data=[]
lowest1=[]

#data_name=[]
#competitor=[]

for i in range (1,number_of_row+1):
    time.sleep(random.randint(2,6))
    keyword_input=worksheet.cell(i,0).value
    print (keyword_input)

 
    # prefix="https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/search/product?disp=list&p="
    url = "https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/search/product"
     
    
    querystring = {"p":str(keyword_input),"sort":"p"}
    r = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    # r=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,  'html.parser')
   
    #competitor_name_div=soup.findAll("div", {"class":"ListItem_shop_Z_sCW"})
    prices=[]
    productprice_div=soup.find("ul", class_="gridList")
    if productprice_div is not None:
        number_result_div=soup.find("div", {"class":"SortBar_sortBar_2CVWp SortBar_store_1U4Du"})
        total_results =number_result_div.find('span', {"class":'SortBar_sortCount_1LpL9 textEllipsis'}).text.strip().split(" ")[0].strip()
        print("Totol Results: ",total_results)
        results.append(total_results)
        product_list =productprice_div.findAll("li",{"class":"BaseGridItem__grid___2wuJ7 imprsn BaseGridItem__multipleImage___37M7b"})
        # print(len(product_list))
        
        for i in product_list: 
            try:
                lowest=i.find("span",{"class":"BaseGridItem__price___31jkj"}).find('em').text.strip()
                print(lowest)
                prices.append(lowest)
            except:
                lowest=i.find("span",{"class":"BaseGridItem__itemInfo___3E5Bx"}).find('em').text.strip()
                print(lowest)
                prices.append(lowest)
    else:
        prices.append("N/A")
        total_results =0    
        results.append(total_results)
        print("Totol Results: ",total_results)
        pass
    data.append({"keyword":keyword_input, "results":total_results, "prices":','.join(prices)})

print(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel('finalresult.xlsx', index = False)
```

Comment: What is the 2nd way ?

Comment: If you wrote this question and answered it by yourself, please clarify the contents of question and answer; it seems like the code for a question is now moved to the answer.